# SQL query based on flag

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help on Mysql query. How do I SUM(Value) that only flagged = 0 but not all zeros in the table but only last straight zeros. Say maybe last 2  straight zero, maybe last 5 straight zero. In the sample picture, last 3 zero.

sample data

[image]

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desired output in text format in the body of your post.

Comment: Check limit  function . Order by some column and using limit sum the last rows

Comment: If you know the number of records having 0, then you can use this query `SELECT SUM(value) FROM table where flag = 0 order by id DESC limit 0, 3` .. In this query, I am using `limit 0, 3`  assuming you know the number of records having flag as 0 are 3 from the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite complicated, but I think It works and may be answer for you

```
    Select sum(`value`) from
            (Select
                `value`,
                @lastval := @lastval + 1 as row_index
                  from yourtable
                  cross join (select @lastval := 0) A) B

            where B.row_index  > (select max(rowindex) from 
                                        (Select
                                            `flag`,
                                            @lastval := @lastval + 1 as rowindex
                                              from yourtable
                                              cross join (select @lastval := 0) C) D

                                            where D.flag = 1)
```

You can optimize my answer in[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b948b2/22)

Comment: this is great! exactly as I need it thanks man you are great coder. i still need to learn more

Comment: It is still complicated, but I can't find something better. You can edit to optimize it on SQLFiddle and update answer if you have simpler query. I like this problem too